# Auto adjust division's height & width in html

Tags: html, css

Hello im basic developer , Following is my html code :-

```
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 divMainContainer" style="overflow:auto;" id="divmsgPost"> // used bootstrap
   <div id="divContent" style="overflow:auto;">
   <span class="wordwrap">
 <------- User's  Content here !-->// can be anything , text or image
   </span>
    </div>
   </div>
```

Css

```
   .divMainContainer {
      margin-left: -3px;
       width: 450px;
     height:auto;
      }

      #divContent 
       {
        height : auto;
        width : 450px;

       }

     .wordwrap {
     white-space: pre-wrap;      /* CSS3 */   
     white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Firefox */    
     white-space: -pre-wrap;     /* Opera <7 */   
     white-space: -o-pre-wrap;   /* Opera 7 */    
     word-wrap: break-word;      /* IE */
      }
```

After , providing above neccessities , what is neccessary to make the `divContent` auto resizable without showing the scroll bars ? Because `overflow:auto` makes the content scroll , but doesn't expand the div according to the user's content. Really need some help to understand which syntax will be neccessary to accomplish what is needed . Thank you

Comment: If you do not use `overflow:auto`, the scrollbars will disappear and the element will grow depending on the input. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: it does get growing but the text (content ) of users gets overlaped on other div's :( , How to fix that ?

Comment: Please provide full code (HTML and CSS) that will allow us to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Added the associated css & modified some html code. :)

Comment: Do you want the `divContent` to expand horizontally or vertically?

Comment: Data is not enough. If you want the div to expand vertically then you code should work perfectly with text content. But for Image larger than 450px (the width you have given) will make the image to overflow. Add max width:100%; for descendant images. Or give min-width:450px; to the div and make it display:inline-block & add in .divMainContainer, text-align:center.

Comment: @rokin wanted to expand vertically

Comment: @vikrant did it solve your issue?

Comment: not actually solved my issue's , but im trying to find another solutions like using bootstrap (auto height increment feature) & other kind of UI to handle it easily :)